# Why didn't an MCB or fuse blow

Tags: ac

I have an associate who attended a boiler system recently where the customer got a shock from touching the boiler casing.
My associate claims there was a fault on a washing machine livening up the earth.
My question is why didn't the MCB or fuse trip? There was no RCD in place

Comment: Perhaps there was another fault like unconnected earth somewhere? How could we guess what was wrong?

Comment: Location? So MCB come in various sizes 10mA or 30mA - easily possible to get a shock and it does not trip. Fuses especially.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes a broken earth was one thing I considered. I'm in the UK, rings mains are 32amp and earth cable should be 16mm² I believe.

Comment: @mkeith MCB just means a Miniature Circuit Breaker.

Comment: "MCB" -> "Miniature Circuit Breaker" (It's really just a *normal* circuit breaker). "RCD" -> "Residual Current Device" (aka GFCI on the other side of the pond).

Comment: UK ring main wiring is 2.5 mm² for L+N and 1.5 mm² for earth as far as I'm aware. 16 mm² would be massive.

Comment: Sounds like a grounding issue.  **livening up the earth**.  That's worth a laugh!  Not if it is grounded properly!

Answer (score 2):

Normal fuses or circuit breakers (including MCD's, miniature circuit breakers) do not trip when small ground fault currents flow through a persons body. They only trip (or blow) when high fault currents occur. Their purpose is primarily to prevent fires caused by hot wires or smoldering insulation. They do not provide protection against shocks and electrocution.

An RCD (similar to a GFCI in North America) is intended to trip when a small ground fault current flows in a person's body. In this case, since no RCD is present, there was no chance for an RCD to operate and protect against shock.

It should not be possible for a metal appliance body to become energized, however, because when the energized line voltage comes into contact with the grounded metal frame, a high fault current SHOULD flow to ground. So most likely there is some ground fault present in this system.